# WordPress shortcode show some mistake

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Which is show category post. But it has some mistake .please anyone fix it .

This my WordPress shortcode

```
   function my_form_shortcode($atts) {
   ob_start();
  $atts = shortcode_atts(
      array(
          'cat' => '1',
         'showposts' => '5', 
     ), $atts, 'my_form_shortcode' );

  //YOUR CODE START

 $recent = new WP_Query(); 
 $query = "cat=".$atts['cat']."&showposts=".$atts['showposts'];
 $recent->query( $query ); 
 $is_first_post = true; 
 while( $recent->have_posts() ) : $recent->the_post(); ?>

 <div class="panel-heading"><?php the_category(', '); ?></div>

<ul class="panel-grid">
 <li class="ex">
<?php 
 if ( $is_first_post  && has_post_thumbnail() ) {
  the_post_thumbnail( 'image', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' )); 
  $is_first_post = false; 
  }
 ?>

 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
 <?php the_title(); ?>
  </a>
 </li>
 </ul>
<?php endwhile; 
//YOUR CODE END

 return ob_get_clean(); 
}

add_shortcode( 'my_form_shortcode', 'my_form_shortcode' );
```

In this code category title name show before all post. But I want to show category title before only 1st post. Whats the wrong in this code. Please, help me ..

Answer (score 0):

try this...
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category_by_id/

```html
function get_the_category_by_ID( $cat_ID ) {
    $cat_ID = (int) $cat_ID;
    $category = get_term( $cat_ID, 'category' );
 
    if ( is_wp_error( $category ) )
        return $category;
 
    return ( $category ) ? $category->name : '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code:

```
<?php
function my_form_shortcode($atts) {
    ob_start();
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'cat' => '1',
        'showposts' => '5', 
    ), $atts, 'my_form_shortcode' );

    //YOUR CODE START

    $recent = new WP_Query(); 
    $query = "cat=".$atts['cat']."&showposts=".$atts['showposts'];
    $recent->query( $query ); 
    $is_first_post = true; ?>
    <div class="panel-heading"><?php the_category(', '); ?></div>
    <?php while( $recent->have_posts() ) : $recent->the_post(); ?>

        <ul class="panel-grid">
            <li class="ex">
            <?php 
                if ( $is_first_post  && has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    the_post_thumbnail( 'image', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' )); 
                    $is_first_post = false; 
                }
            ?>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <?php endwhile; 
    //YOUR CODE END

    return ob_get_clean(); 
}

add_shortcode( 'my_form_shortcode', 'my_form_shortcode' );
```